# How to implement ajax which calls php function which implements httpget method and returns a response as json to ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

**MY AJAX function**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sub").click(function()
        { 
         console.log("Ajax out");
         var isbn= $('#isbn').val();    
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"httprequestget.php",
                data : "isbnn="+isbn,

                success:function(response)
                {

                 console.log("Ajax - in ( response)");
                 alert(response);




                }
               });
               });

           });
```

**MY httpgetrequest.php**

```
$isbnn='12345';
$result2=myRestapiGET($isbnn);

 function myRestapiGET($isbn)
 {
     $url = 'http://localhost:8080/Scanbook-server/books/'.$isbn;
     $options = array(
     'http' => array
     (
    'method'  => 'GET'
     ),
                     );
       $context  = stream_context_create($options);
       $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

     return $result;
 }
```

I want to return results as json format retrieved by get function in php to ajax.But when i try without the function to just echo some random variable I do get the response.

Comment: You don't need to use a content for `method => GET`, since that's the default for `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are not sending the data as an object and that is why it only works whenever you try it with a random variable. Please try with the following:

```
$("#sub").click(function() { 

    var isbn= $('#isbn').val();    

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'httprequestget.php', 
        data: { isbn: isbn }, 
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Ajax - in ( response)");
            alert(response); 
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `data:` can be either an object or a string.

Comment: thanks for the response.But i figured it out my UI was form type so i removed the form and did it in regular without form.

Comment: I was thinking about that last night but was not able to comment. Well, you can still keep the form data.. you just needed to use somthing like this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly.

Add the dataType attribute in the `$.ajax` function :
`dataType: "json"`

And use the php `json_encode` to return the response in `Scanbook-server/books/` script :

`echo json_encode(["book" => "foo", "isbn" =>13456, "response" => 'success']);`

Comment: thanks for the response.But i figured it out my UI was form type so i removed the form and did it in regular without form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the result of the function to send it back to the client:

```
$isbnn = $_POST['isbnn'];
$result2=myRestapiGET($isbnn);
echo $result2;
```

Comment: thanks for the response.But i figured it out my UI was form type so i removed the form and did it in regular without form.

Comment: @KarthicParamasivam You should post an answer that shows how you solved it.

Comment: yes the problem was with my UI. I removed html form submit and changed it to button.now my function runs

Comment: That is not very clear. Show the details in an answer, not a comment.